# Select2 Optgroup Result Set

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I was hoping to receive help with the following problem.

I get back the following JSON data:

```
{
    "0": {
    "Name": "Hello World OPTGROUP",
    "values": [
        {
            "Vector": "[REDACTED]",
            "Name": "Hello World",
            "Value": "[REDACTED]",
            "Matched": null
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "1": {
    "Name": "Lorem Ipsum OPTGROUP",
    "values": [
        {
            "Vector": "[REDACTED]",
            "Name": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "Value": "[REDACTED]",
            "Matched": null
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I go about build a *processResults* dropdown result set that includes  labels for each array?

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Hello World OPTGROUP">
    <option>Values[0] Value</option>
    <option>Values[1] Value</option>
    <optgroup label="Lorem Ipsum OPTGROUP">
    <option>Values[0] Value</option>
    <option>Values[1] Value</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data wasn't quite ...complete so I put in some {} where I thought you needed them.

One way to do this would be:

```js
const data = [{
    "0": {
    "Name": "Hello World OPTGROUP",
      "values": [
          {
              "Vector": "[REDACTED]",
              "Name": "Hello World",
              "Value": "[REDACTED]",
              "Matched": null
          }
      ]
    }
},    
{
    "1": {
      "Name": "Lorem Ipsum OPTGROUP",
      "values": [
          {
              "Vector": "[REDACTED]",
              "Name": "Lorem Ipsum",
              "Value": "[REDACTED]",
              "Matched": null
          },
          {
              "Vector": "[REDACTED]",
              "Name": "Lorem Ipsum",
              "Value": "[REDACTED]2",
              "Matched": null
          }
       ]
    }
}];
const optMap = e => `<option>${e.Value}</option>`
let templateInner = data
  .map(e=>e[Object.keys(e)])
  .map(e=>`
    <optgroup label="${e.Name}">
    ${e.values.map(optMap).join('')}`)
  .join('')
let template = `<select>${templateInner}
</select>`
console.log(template)
```